# CrUX Core Web Vital Report Missing dates

Tags: report, core-web-vitals

There is a specific CrUX report that I have created, that currently display only "September 2023" as the only available month to see the data.

The other CrUX reports I have created display all months, from August 2019 to September 2023.

I'd like to ask why is that happening and how to fix it.

I try adding an SQL Query to add in the remaining dates but Google Cloud that the command exceeded my free limits.

Comment: Are you saying that for a given origin/website you only have September info but for others you have all of them? It could well be that that website just wasn't in CrUX prior to that. If you can share the origin this can be checked. Also share your SQL and can see why that exceeded your limits as the CrUX data is usually super cheap to query.